# How to publish a hidden post on Lemoon?

Tags: lemoon

I'm trying to create a blog post that is available by entering the permalink directly but does not get listed on the parent content (the blog) page so that casual browsers of the blog will not see it, but people with the link will. Is this possible? I would expect to find this on the Visibility tab, but I don't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the Visibility tab, but you need to add a check in the blog post search to make it work. Here are two ways to do it:

### Not searchable, not listed

If you don't want the blog post to be found through a search either, but instead only through a direct link, you can do the following:

First, set "Include in search" under the Visibility tab to "No" for the posts you don't want to show up.

Then (assuming you're using the standard blog template) go to the code behind and set "SearchNonSearchable" to false:

```
query.SearchNonSearchable = false
```

### Searchable, not listed

If you want the post to still be searchable but not listed, instead do the following:

First, set "Display in meny" under the Visibility tab to "No" for the posts you don't want to show up.

Then add the following to the query in the code behind:

```
query.DisplayInMenu = DisplayInMenu.Sitemap;
```

This is assuming you're using the standard content type for blog posts, which has "Display in sitemap" set as standard.